# Heroku Node.js Angular build failing

Tags: angular, heroku, npm, deployment, package.json

My app is working fine when hosted locally, but when I try to deploy the build fails with the following output log:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  8.10.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.4.1

       Resolving node version 8.10.0...
       Downloading and installing node 8.10.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.4.1 (replacing 5.6.0)...
       npm 6.4.1 installed

-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build

-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE
       npm ERR! typeerror Error: Argument #5: Expected object but got string
       npm ERR! typeerror     at inflatableChild (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:93:3)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at BB.each (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at tryCatcher (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.gotValue (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:155:18)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.gotAccum (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:144:25)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.tryCatcher (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromise (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Promise._settlePromises (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Async._drainQueue (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Async._drainQueues (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/tmp/build_8521c67f1a08023343c4f34aedc664fb/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
       npm ERR! typeerror     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
       npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
       npm ERR! typeerror     <https://npm.community>

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Mus2Z/_logs/2018-11-18T01_38_26_671Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "scheduling",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --target=production"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.10.0",
    "npm" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ActionPackedJack/Restaurant-Schedule"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": ">=1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": ">=4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": ">=2.2.0"
  }
}
```

And here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}))
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/dist/public/')));
app.get('/*', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/dist'));
})
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public/dist'))
require('./server/config/mongoose.js');
var routes_setter = require('./server/config/routes.js');
routes_setter(app);
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'))
});
```

I read another instance of a user solving this problem by deleting their package-lock.json file, but trying that resulted in a different error, "The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, please and thank you!

Comment: removing package-lock.json file did work for me

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json doesn't have devDependencies, are they needed?

I followed this link: 
https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147
but pay attention to his updated link for updates: 
https://medium.com/@shubhsharma10/how-to-deploy-angular-6-app-to-heroku-52b73ac7a3aa

My package.json file in my heroku app looks like:

```
{
"name": "my-app",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "node server.js",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.3",
"@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
"angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"curl": "^0.1.4",
"express": "^4.16.4",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"latest": "^0.2.0",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"popper.js": "^1.12.9",
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
"typescript": "~3.1.1",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
"@angular/cli": "^7.0.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.3",
"@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~3.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "~3.1.1"
 },
 "engines": {
"node": "10.12.0",
"npm": "6.4.1"
}
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that was really helpful.  I had a lot of other bizarre file paths and such to reconcile, but those dependency declarations seemed like part of the solution.  Finally up and running.  Thanks!